# Active Directory, LDAP UserPrincipal

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Got this information when I wrote out the DistinguishedName property on UserPrincipal class.

```
CN=Test Testie, OU=123,OU=Company,OU=Accounts,DC=myServer,DC=local
```

And im woundering if there is a property to get the nr 123 from OU. Is there any other property to get that or is this the best way to filter out my information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\No.  There is no "Parent" property.

Every object bellow the root has a parent being either an organizational unit (OU=) on a container (CN=).  So just parse what is between the first two commas and remove OU= and CN=.  That way you have the Name property.

Beware that it is possible to have objects with commas in their names. It then look like this:

> Great OU, The
>
> CN=Test Testie,OU=Great OU\,The,OU=Company,OU=Accounts,DC=myServer,DC=local
>
> Testie, Test
>
> CN=Testie\, Test
> ,OU=123,The,OU=Company,OU=Accounts,DC=myServer,DC=local

So you need to check for a backslah before parsing!  If found, you then need to parse, between the first and the third comma.

[Here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2253.txt) is a link about "special" characters in Distinguished Names.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's working but it doesn't feels like the best practice to do like this:

```
        var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "myDomain.local");
        var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "myUser");
        var auth = user.GetAuthorizationGroups().Any(x => x.Name.Contains("myGroup"));
```

Because the thing is that I need to use contains because the group could look like this:

```
myGroup.xxxx.111
```

Any better way to soulve this?